# Shortest route with a requirements set

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

Suppose you have a weighted connected graph, $G(V, E)$, with $n$ nodes such that every node has a edge to every other node (a large clique). You are also given a set of sets, $\{l_1, l_2, ... l_n\}$ so that every $l_i$ corresponds to $v_i \in V$.

Starting from any node $s \in V$, find the shortest route $G^\prime(V^\prime, E^\prime)$ so that for every corresponding $l$ and $l^\prime$, $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}l_{i} = \bigcup_{j=1}^{k}l_{j}^\prime$, and it terminates on $s$.

In case my rather poor notation is insufficient in getting the idea across, imagine you had a shopping list of items and a bunch of stores to choose from. You can travel from any store to any store. Not every store will have every item you need and there will be some overlap between stores. Find the shortest route to pick up all the items you need and return home.

Comment: This is a generalization of the well-known traveling salesman problem (in which case for each node $v_i$, $l_i=\{v_i\}$), which is an NP-complete problem. Hence, this is also an NP-complete problem (since the standard TSP is polynomial-time reducible to this problem), meaning there is no known polynomial-time algorithm to solve this in its general form.

Comment: @karakusc If it cannot be solved in P, can it at least be approximated?

Comment: I do not know any. There are approximation algorithms for TSP, but I do not know if they generalize to your problem.